# Building HTML in Java code only

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc

What is the simplest, fastest way to create a String object (I suppose) that contains HTML (with correct encoding), which I can return for example in `@ResponseBody` (Spring MVC) ?

Comment: Depends on from what you are creating that HTML but, from what you have mentioned in your question i will say StringBuilder!

Comment: This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45713037/8429746) must be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There can be several approaches.

First you can use String, or StringBuilder. This is good for extremely short HTMLs like `<html>Hello, <b>world</b></html>`.

If HTML is more complicated it is easier to use some API. Take a look on these links:

http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/apiDocs/org/apache/html/dom/HTMLBuilder.html

[Java HTML Builder (anti-template) library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583846/java-html-builder-anti-template-library)

or search `html builder java` in google.

Other possibility is templating. If you actually have a template where you wish to replace a couple of words you can write your HTML as an `*.html` file with `{0}`, `{}` marks for parameters. Then just use `java.text.MessageFormat` to create actual HTML text.

The next approach is to use "real" template engine like Velocity.

Answer (score 6):

Does this work for you?

```
StringBuilder htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
htmlBuilder.append("<html>");
htmlBuilder.append("<head><title>Hello World</title></head>");
htmlBuilder.append("<body><p>Look at my body!</p></body>");
htmlBuilder.append("</html>");
String html = htmlBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: when you say encoding, do you mean UTF-8 etc? or the "&gt;" thing?

Comment: Yes, UTF-8. I say about something like that `htmlBuilder.append("<head><title>Hello Łódź</title></head>");`

Comment: Java use UTF-8 encoding internally, so whatever you type in Java is in UTF-8 encoding already. Does that answer your question?

Comment: If you know that the String will be longer than sixteen characters, better allocate a large initial buffer: `new StringBuilder(1000)`

Comment: Just for completion, values of attributes can be incorporated using String.format, i.e: htmlBuilder.append(String.format("<option value=\"%s\">%s</option>", value, label));

Answer (score 2):

As of Java 13 there is a new feature being added called **Text Blocks** .  To use a Text Block you must use *three* double quotes AKA `"""`, to open and close the `String`.

This feature allows us to build something such as `html` without needing to concatenate Strings, handle new lines, or use a library and build the `String` very clearly and easily.

Here is a short example of using this new feature for `html`:

```
String html = """
              <html>
                  <body>
                      <p>Hello, world</p>
                  </body>
              </html>
              """;
```

This is equivalent to the below code without using Text Blocks:

```
String html = "<html>\n" +
              "    <body>\n" +
              "        <p>Hello, world</p>\n" +
              "    </body>\n" +
              "</html>\n";
```

**Source:** [JEP 355: Text Blocks](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/355)

Answer (score 1):

Using [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) or [wffweb](https://webfirmframework.com/) will be the simplest way to build HTML from Java code. You can dynamically generate HTML using it.

**Eg for jsoup:**

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<html></html>");
doc.body().addClass("body-styles-cls");
doc.body().appendElement("div");
System.out.println(doc.toString());
```

will print

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body class=" body-styles-cls">
  <div></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

---

**Eg for wffweb:**

```
Html rootTag = new Html(null).give(html -> {
    new Head(html);        
    new Body(html).give(body -> {
        new NoTag(body, "Hello World");            
    });
});
rootTag.setPrependDocType(true);
System.out.println(rootTag.toHtmlString());
```

will print

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      Hello World
   </body>
</html>
```

You can also write to `OutputStream` in specified charset encoding using [`toOutputStream​(OutputStream os, String charset)`](https://webfirmframework.github.io/wffweb/wffweb-javadoc/com/webfirmframework/wffweb/tag/html/AbstractHtml.html#toOutputStream(java.io.OutputStream,java.lang.String)) method.

Answer (score 0):

Good way is extracting the style=""s into the head?

```
sb.append("<style>" +
"td { padding: 6px; border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: left; }" + 
"th { background: #333; color: white; font-weight: bold; padding: 6px; border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: left;}" +
"</style>");
```

helper methods:

```
void appendTag(StringBuilder sb, String tag, String contents) {
    sb.append('<').append(tag).append('>');
    sb.append(contents);
    sb.append("</").append(tag).append('>');
}
void appendDataCell(StringBuilder sb, String contents) {
    appendTag(sb, "td", contents);
}
void appendHeaderCell(StringBuilder sb, String contents) {
    appendTag(sb, "th", contents);
}
```